# Can multispectral imaging be used for identification of materials, substituting for hyperspectral imaging?

Tags: spectroscopy, polymers, plastics, ir-spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

Nowadays a lot of research and applications are using Hyperspectral Imaging for identification and segregation of plastics by material. But the cost of a HSI system is quite high.

Could a multispectral solution yield good enough results, to substitute for HSI?

Comment: There is an explanation /comparison here https://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/hyperspectral-and-multispectral-imaging/ . Notice that this company has a commercial interest in these methods.

Comment: You might be more specific regarding the application involved. The link provided by porphyrin is very informative.